# Setting global block attribute value

Tags: plugin-development, block-editor

I have a scenario where I will have to use the same API key for all the blocks of the same namespace that is present and that will be created new. So when user inputs on one block through a form, it will update on all the blocks of the particular namespace instantly.

Currently when `register_block_type()` and `props.setAttributes` method is used, the values for each attribute is unique for each of the block. I have seen the documentation. I couldn't see a standard way for sharing the same value across blocks.

**Register code:**

```
registerBlockType("namespace", {
  title: "Plugin title",
  category: "common",
  attributes: {
    apiKey: { type: "string" },
```

**Handling submit from the form inside InspectorControls:**

```
<InspectorControls>
      <PanelBody>
        <form id="api-key-input" onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}>
          <input
            type="password"
            ref={inputRef}
            defaultValue={props.attributes.apiKey}
          />
          <input type="submit" />
        </form>
 </InspectorControls>

function handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  props.setAttributes({ apiKey: inputRef.current.value });
}
```

The methods that I have looked at so far.

1. Storing the attributes in the database using `update_option` but I did not see any `get_option` for the Gutenberg block.
2. `wp.data.subscribe` way of dispatching to the blocks required.
3. Creating a registry store and managing the overall value using states.

Is there an easiest/safest way of doing this that I am missing, like setting an option or supports value?

Comment: I'd probably use method 1 (storing to a db option), but how is the API key being used in the `save` function? And at the moment, what's the solution you're using - is it method 2 (using `wp.data.subscribe`)? What's the full code of your `edit` function?

Comment: @SallyCJ Thanks for the reply! The API key is being used in the edit function itself to fetch the required data and that data is being saved in a data attribute. Once the API data is fetched I use the attributes from the PHP `render_callback` to render the frontend component. Save function just returns null.

`wp.data.subscribe` works for only per page blocks, right? That's not feasible if that's the case. Is there any `get_option` for the JS side for getting the value stored in the database?

Comment: It's similar to a Reusable block but only with a same specific attribute value instead of all. So I think there must be a reusable property somewhere to be used.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. I haven't checked the other methods, but as for "Is there any `get_option` for the JS side" - yes, there is, and I can provide an example, if you want?

Comment: @SallyCJ An example would help, yes! :)

Comment: I am using a function component only. @SallyCJ I converted the other solution to functional component but I want to know your way too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137530/discussion-between-sally-cj-and-m4n0).

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of [register_post_field()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_field/) to add the API key to the post object which you then can retrieve via [getEditedPostAttribute()](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/data/data-core-editor/) in the editor.
In `register_post_field()` you can define by yourself via `get_callback`/`update_callback` how/where the API key should be saved like post meta or an option.

To update the API key in the editor use the [editPost()](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/data/data-core-editor/#editpost) dispatch function which will invoke your `update_callback`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! I made use of this method: https://wholesomecode.ltd/using-options-to-store-data-in-the-wordpress-block-editor-gutenberg Although I can use your methods for my other functionalities.